# TypeError: integer argument expected, got 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

El error ocurre en el login de un programa , he estado leyendo y encontre una solucion con el open , pero no me funciona alguien que me ayude , gracias de antemano.

```
def login():

    user2=str(input("Nombre de usuario:"))
    user__file2=open("login/users.txt" ,mode= "r")
    user__file2.read(user2)
    user__file2.close()

    contraseña2=str(input("Contraseña : "))
    pwd__file2=open("login/passwords.txt" ,mode= "r")
    pwd__file2.read(contraseña2)
    pwd__file2.close()

    if user2 == user__file2:

        print("Nombre de usuario correcto")
        if pwd__file2 == contraseña2:
            print("Acceso completo obtenido")
    else:
        print("Credenciales de acceso no validas", datetime.date.today())

        exit()
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido de de tus dos archivos?¿Qué pretendes hacer exactamente? ¿Que quieres conseguir con `user__file2.read(user2)`?

Comment: Verdaderamente ahi me falto resto del codigo , en si , es un login y register , en donde al registrarse se alamacena los datos en un archivo txt y luego en def login se lee para comprobar si es cierto y con lo cual se autoriza al resto , esto se hace gracias a user__file2.read(user2)

Comment: Perdon , eso ya esta solucionado , gracias FJSevilla, resulta que no lo pense y es que con user__file2.read(user2) no consigo nada , eso me pasa por copiar y pegar de user__file.write(user) . deveras gracias

Comment: Pero `user__file2` es un fichero ( `_io.TextIOWrapper` más propiamente), si pretendes leer su contenido debes hacer algo como `user = user__file2.read()` a no ser que uses una función `open` y `read` propias...... ¿Tus ficheros almacenan un solo usuario (una sola línea) o varios (más de una línea)? Es necesario que muestres la estructura de estos archivos en tal caso para poder ayudarte.

Comment: En si solamente muestra una sola linea , la idea es que para que me deje pasar el login , lea las credenciales escritas en el txt , antes del login ocurre el def register en donde se escribe las credenciales y mi idea es que en def login se lean y , tras leerse , con el operador == comprobar si son iguales

Comment: A `read()` se le puede pasar eventualmente un tamaño `int`, por lo que se ve le estarías pasando una cadena `user2`, ahí seguramente el error, pero tal como te comenta FJSevilla, si el archivo `users.txt` tiene más de un usuario la lógica debiera ser totalmente distinta.

Comment: Solamente almacena un usuario y una contraseña

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas intentando comparar la entrada del usuario con el contenido de un archivo de texto de una sola línea que almacenan el usuario y la contraseña estas cometiendo un error al leerlo:

Para obtener el contendido del fichero debes hacer algo  como  `user = user__file2.read()`, donde asignas la cadena a la variable `user`. Si solo tienes una línea puedes usar `readline()`.

Recuerda eliminar el salto de línea a la hora de comparar si existe (depende como crees el fichero), puedes usar `str.strip()` para ello:

Puedes usar `with` para asegurarte del cierre de los archivos sin necesidad de hacerlo explícito.

Si usas Python 3 como indicas, `input` ya retorna una cadena. El casting no es necesario por tanto.

```
def login():

    input_user = input("Nombre de usuario: ")
    input_pwd =  input("Contraseña : ")

    with open("login/users.txt") as f:
        user = f.readline().strip("\n\r")

    with open("login/passwords.txt") as f:   
        pwd = f.readline().strip(a.strip("\n\r")

    if user == input_user and pwd == input_pwd:
        print("Credenciales de acceso válidas")
        print("Acceso completo obtenido")
    else:
        print("Credenciales de acceso no válidas", datetime.date.today())
        exit()
```

Recuerda que almacenar credenciales en un fichero de texto plano es muy inseguro.

---

**Edición:**

Como muy bien apreció @PatricioMoracho, existe un error en la lógica de tu condicional que ocasiona que si se ingresa un usuario válido pero contraseña incorrecta se valida el login. He optado por no informar por separado de la validez del usuario, aunque si deseas este comportamiento como pareces indicar en tu código puedes hacer algo como:

```
if user == input_user:
    print("Nombre de usuario correcto")
    if pwd == input_pwd:
        print("Credenciales de acceso válidas\nAcceso completo obtenido")
        return
    else:
        print("Contraseña incorrecta")
else:
    print("Usuario incorrecto")
print("Credenciales de acceso no válidas", datetime.date.today())
exit()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos ,da gusto que te ayuden la verdad, un saludo

Comment: FJSevilla agrego un comentario más, el código original tiene un error lógico, si el usuario es correcto pero la contraseña no, eventualmente permitiría el login.

Comment: Solucionado , gracias por avisarme , no me fije

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho por la observación, tienes toda la razón, me centré en lo anterior y pasé completamente por alto el condicional. Corregido. Un saludo.